# Return rows where column matches all values in a set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table structure  in mysql:

```
ID  USER_ID TYPE
1   1       B
2   3       B
3   4       B
4   3       C
5   3       D
6   4       C
7   4       D
8   3       B
```

Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df38f/1

I have a requirement like get all 'USER_ID' having 'Type' as B and C.
ie I need a result as below:

```
USER_ID
3
4
```

Comment: try my solution below which achieves the solution using group_concat and FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Also a suggestion, use some other column name for type as it seems to be a keyword. Yes you are using it enclosed in ` `, but its better not to use keywords as column names

Comment: user_id 1 is also in B, shouldn't it be in result?

Comment: Did you check my answer below along with the sql fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT group_concat(`type`) AS types,user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE `type` IN('B','C') 
group by user_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('B',types)>0 && FIND_IN_SET('C',types)>0
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ef8e/2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tablename
WHERE type IN ('B', 'C')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING cnt = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117d8/15)

This assumes that `user_id` + `type` combinations are unique. If not, you can make a subquery that gets distinct values:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM (SELECT distinct user_id, type
      FROM tablename
      WHERE type IN ('B', 'C')) x
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING cnt = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df38f/12)

Comment: @Barmar..what if 2b's occur and still the count will be 2

Comment: @Barmar I Agree what Avinash Kothamasu  told, check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df38f/1

Comment: Use the second query. I added a fiddle for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct firsttable.user_id
FROM t1 firsttable, t1 secondtable
WHERE firsttable.type ='B' and secondtable.type ='C'  and firsttable.user_id =secondtable.user_id
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2be9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please modify this to suit your needs:

```
select * from (select USER_ID from T1 where USER_ID IN 
(select USER_ID from T1 where T1.TYPE = 'B')) t
INNER JOIN  
((select USER_ID from T1 where USER_ID IN 
(select USER_ID from T1 where T1.TYPE = 'C'))) t2
on t.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID group by t.user_id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117d8/38)

**Edit: a better approach**

```
select * from (select USER_ID from T1 where T1.TYPE = 'B') t
INNER JOIN  
(select USER_ID from T1 where T1.TYPE = 'C') t2
on t.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID group by t.user_id
```

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117d8/41)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) cnt
FROM T1
WHERE type IN ('B', 'C')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING cnt >= 2;

user_id cnt
3       3
4       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM T1
WHERE type IN ('B', 'C')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING cnt >= 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/451e61/4)

Answer (score -1):

```
select USER_ID from ( 
    ( select USER_ID from table where TYPE = 'B' ) as t1 join 
    ( select USER_ID from table where TYPE = 'C' ) as t2 on
    on t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID );
```