# Select record in one table which must have certain rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have difficulty in retrieving data.

Persons

```
PId | Name
---------------
1   | David
2   | Steven
3   | John
```

PersonDays

```
PId | Days
---------------
1   | 0
1   | 1
1   | 2
1   | 3
2   | 1
2   | 2
2   | 3
2   | 4
3   | 0
3   | 1
3   | 4
```

I want to retrieve records from Persons which have Day values of 1,2,3 in PersonDays table.

So, David and Steven are the correct answer.

How can I write a query in MySQL?

### Edit

Day values are dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return rows where column matches all values in a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216419/return-rows-where-column-matches-all-values-in-a-set)

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct p.* 
from persons p 
     join PersonDays pd on p.PId=pd.PId and pd.Days in (1,2,3)
```

Updated

```
SELECT p.PId, p.name,COUNT(pd.PId) AS days_count 
FROM Persons p 
INNER JOIN PersonDays pd on p.PId=pd.PId and pd.Days in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY p.PId
HAVING days_count=3
```

Comment: Won't this also return John? He has Day = 1, but not Day = 2 and Day = 3.

Comment: this will return John as well, which is not required

Comment: @Barmar I improved the query to use ALL the days by AND

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select * from Persons where PId  in (
select PId  from PersonDays where Days in (1,2,3)) as P 
where P.PId = Persons.PId;
```

Comment: He wants people who have all 3 days, not any of the 3. This query will return John, which is not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aff15/1)**

**QUERY**

```
SELECT p.name AS 'Person Name'
FROM `person` AS p
JOIN (SELECT p.pid AS 'pid',GROUP_CONCAT(pd.days) AS 'days'
FROM `person` AS p
JOIN `persondays` AS pd ON p.pid = pd.pid
GROUP BY p.pid) AS sub ON sub.pid = p.pid
WHERE sub.days LIKE '%1%2%3%'
```

hope this will help you...!